# Rails Active Admin update user status on show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I've got Rails 6 app with AA on board. My User model has `status:string` field which I want to give ability to change that field from `active` to `inactive` by admin user via ActiveAdmin. Admin should be able to update this field in the show view. The view should display something like below:

```
#when account is inactive
Account status:
Inactive
Activate account #this is the link to change user status

#when account is active
Account status:
Active
Suspend account #this is the link to change user status
```

To do so I've got below active admin code:

```
#admin/users.rb

ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :status

  collection_action :update_status, method: :post do
    user.update!(status: 'active')
    redirect_to user_path, notice: 'User status updated'
  end

  show do
    div do
      h3 'Some custom partial in show action'
      render partial: 'show'
    end
    active_admin_comments
  end
end
```

with the views

```
#views/admin/users/_show.html.erb
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <b>
        <th>Account status:</th>
      </b>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><%= @user.status %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'>
        <% if @user.status == 'active' %>
          <%= link_to 'Suspend user', update_status_admin_users_path(@user) %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to 'Activate user', update_status_admin_users_path(@user) %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With the above code I'm getting an error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in Admin::UsersController#show
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

Comment: You are not responding to the correct format. Can you show us your `Admin::UsersController` as well as the request that you're making? A curl would do. Also, `views/admin/users/_show.rb` should probably be `views/admin/users/_show.erb`.

Comment: @KamilGwóźdź my mistake, it's `views/admin/users/_show.erb ` instead. I don't have `Admin::UsersController` why should I even have one? What request? request is sent inside the application via `show` view.

Comment: Ups sorry, just checked how the active admin gem works, the controller is generated dynamically. Can u show us the failing request anyway? It should be visible in browser's dev tools in the network tab.

Comment: @KamilGwóźdź no idea what you're talking about and why do you need this. All I've got is browser's console is `GET http://localhost:3000/admin/users/update_status.1 406 (Not Acceptable)`